# Is there a way to return a full formatted address using map quest api?

Tags: json, api, geocoding, mapquest

I'm using MapQuest's GeoCoding API for a weather app I'm creating (this is due to having many complications using google's API), and the response returns each aspect of the address as a separate value, however unlike Google's API, there does not seem to be a value that returns the full formatted address (i.e 10 Duke Street, Putney, London, SW15 6EH, United Kingdom).

Am I missing something, or do I have to recreate this manually?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In all the examples, I only see the same format of JSON. You will need to concat your own address from the nodes. from: https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/geocoding-api/reverse/get/

Answer (score 0):

Use the outformat function
[Reverse Geocode](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/geocoding-api/reverse/get/)

> outFormat
>
> optional, defaults to json
>
> Specifies the format of the response. Must be one of the following, if supplied:
>
> json
>
> xml
>
> csv (character delimited)
>
> Example: XML response
>
> outFormat=xml

If you return the data as a csv from the API it is closer to the format you require as an address.

```
"Country","State","County","City","PostalCode","Street","Lat","Lng","DragPoint","LinkId","Type","GeocodeQualityCode","GeocodeQuality","SideOfStreet","DisplayLat","DisplayLng"
"US","FL","Duval","Jacksonville","32225","12714 Ashley Melisse Blvd","30.333472","-81.470448","false","0","s","L1AAA","ADDRESS","R","30.333472","-81.470448"
```